# Query response size limit on appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Appengine docs mention a 1Mb limit on both entity size and batch get requests (db.get()):
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html

Is there also a limit on the total size of all entities returned by a query for a single fetch() call?

Example query:

```
db.Model.all().fetch(1000)
```

Update: As of 1.4.0 batch get limits have been removed!

- Size and quantity limits on datastore batch get/put/delete operations have 
  been removed. Individual entities are still limited to 1 MB, but your app 
  may 
  batch as many entities together for get/put/delete calls as the overall 
  datastore deadline will allow for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theres [no longer a limit](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/02/app-engine-sdk-131-including-major.html) on the number of entities that can be returned by a query, but the same entity size limit applies when you are actually retrieving / iterating over the entities.  This will only be on a single entity at a time though; it is not a limit on the total size of all entities returned by the query.

Bottom line: as long as you don't have a single entity that is > 1Mb you should be OK with queries.

Comment: Thanks Karl.  Would you happen to know the size limit on the total size of entities for a query (e.g. for a single fetch())?

Comment: I don't think there is one; i think the only limit is in the timeout of the entire request that you would run into if you tried iterating over the results of a query that had a million results.

Answer (score 3):

I tried it out on production and you can indeed exceed 1 Mb total for a query.  I stopped testing at around 20 Mb total response size.

```
from app import models

# generate 1Mb string
a = 'a'
while len(a) < 1000000:
    a += 'a'

# text is a db.TextProperty()
c = models.Comment(text=a)
c.put()


for c in models.Comment.all().fetch(100):
    print c
```

Output:

```
<app.models.Comment object at 0xa98f8a68a482e9f8>
<app.models.Comment object at 0xa98f8a68a482e9b8>
<app.models.Comment object at 0xa98f8a68a482ea78>
<app.models.Comment object at 0xa98f8a68a482ea38>
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a size limit; the [quotas and limits](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits) section explicitly states there is a 1 megabyte limit to db API calls.

You will not be able to db.get(list_of_keys) if the **total** size of the entities in the batch is over 1 megabyte.  Likewise, you will not be able to put a batch if the total size of the entities in the batch is over 1 megabyte.

The 1,000 entity limit has been removed, but (at present) you will need to ensure the total size of your batches is less than 1 megabyte yourself.

Comment: While your information is correct, I should clarify that the question is about the limit for *queries* and not batch fetch.